# Why I am seeing lot of TimeoutException if any one server goes down?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, futuretask

Here is my DataClientFactory class.

```
public class DataClientFactory {
    public static IClient getInstance() {
        return ClientHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class ClientHolder {
        private static final DataClient INSTANCE = new DataClient();
        static {
            new DataScheduler().startScheduleTask();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my DataClient class.

```
public class DataClient implements IClient {

    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    // for initialization purpose
    public DataClient() {
        try {
            new DataScheduler().callDataService();
        } catch (Exception ex) { // swallow the exception
            // log exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse getDataSync(DataKey dataKeys) {
        DataResponse response = null;
        try {
            Future<DataResponse> handle = getDataAsync(dataKeys);
            response = handle.get(dataKeys.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // log error
            response = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_TIMEOUT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log error
            response = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.ERROR_CLIENT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public Future<DataResponse> getDataAsync(DataKey dataKeys) {
        Future<DataResponse> future = null;
        try {
            DataTask dataTask = new DataTask(dataKeys, restTemplate);
            future = service.submit(dataTask);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log error
        }

        return future;
    }
}
```

I get my client instance from the above factory as shown below and then make a call to `getDataSync` method by passing `DataKey` object. DataKey object has `userId` and `Timeout` values in it. Now after this, call goes to my `DataTask` class to `call` method as soon as `handle.get` is called.

```
IClient dataClient = DataClientFactory.getInstance();

long userid = 1234l;
long timeout_ms = 500;

DataKey keys = new DataKey.Builder().setUserId(userid).setTimeout(timeout_ms)
            .remoteFlag(false).secondaryFlag(true).build();

// call getDataSync method
DataResponse dataResponse = dataClient.getDataSync(keys);
System.out.println(dataResponse);
```

Here is my DataTask class which has all the logic -

```
public class DataTask implements Callable<DataResponse> {

    private DataKey dataKeys;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public DataTask(DataKey dataKeys, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.dataKeys = dataKeys;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse call() {

        DataResponse dataResponse = null;
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

        int serialId = getSerialIdFromUserId();

        boolean remoteFlag = dataKeys.isRemoteFlag();
        boolean secondaryFlag = dataKeys.isSecondaryFlag();

        List<String> hostnames = new LinkedList<String>();

        Mappings mappings = ClientData.getMappings(dataKeys.whichFlow());

        String localPrimaryAdress = null;
        String remotePrimaryAdress = null;
        String localSecondaryAdress = null;
        String remoteSecondaryAdress = null;

        // use mappings object to get above Address by using serialId and basis on 
        // remoteFlag and secondaryFlag populate the hostnames linked list

        if (remoteFlag && secondaryFlag) {
            hostnames.add(localPrimaryHostIPAdress);
            hostnames.add(localSecondaryHostIPAdress);
            hostnames.add(remotePrimaryHostIPAdress);
            hostnames.add(remoteSecondaryHostIPAdress);
        } else if (remoteFlag && !secondaryFlag) {
            hostnames.add(localPrimaryHostIPAdress);
            hostnames.add(remotePrimaryHostIPAdress);
        } else if (!remoteFlag && !secondaryFlag) {
            hostnames.add(localPrimaryHostIPAdress);
        } else if (!remoteFlag && secondaryFlag) {
            hostnames.add(localPrimaryHostIPAdress);
            hostnames.add(localSecondaryHostIPAdress);
        }

        for (String hostname : hostnames) {
            // If host name is null or host name is in local block host list, skip sending request to this host
            if (hostname == null || ClientData.isHostBlocked(hostname)) {
                continue;
            }

            try {
                String url = generateURL(hostname);
                response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, dataKeys.getEntity(), String.class);

                // make DataResponse

                break;

            } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
                // make DataResponse
                return dataResponse;
            } catch (HttpServerErrorException ex) {
                // make DataResponse
                return dataResponse;
            } catch (RestClientException ex) {
                // If it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down.
                // Add this server to block host list 
                ClientData.blockHost(hostname);
                // log an error

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // If it comes here, then it means some weird things has happened.
                // log an error
                // make DataResponse
            }
        }

        return dataResponse;
    }

    private String generateURL(final String hostIPAdress) {
        // make an url
    }


    private int getSerialIdFromUserId() {
        // get the id
    }
}
```

Now basis on `userId`, I will get the `serialId` and then get the list of hostnames, I am suppose to make a call depending on what flag is passed. Then I iterate the `hostnames` list and make a call to the servers. Let's say, if I have four hostnames (A, B, C, D) in the linked list, then I will make call to A first and if I get the data back, then return the DataResponse back. But suppose if A is down, then I need to add A to block list instantly so that no other threads can make a call to A hostname. And then make a call to hostname B and get the data back and return the response (or repeat the same thing if B is also down).

I have a background thread as well which runs every 10 minutes and it gets started as soon we get the client instance from the factory and it parses my another service URL to get the list of block hostnames that we are not supposed to make a call. Since it runs every 10 minutes so any servers which are  down, it will get the list after 10 minutes only, In general suppose if A is down, then my service will provide A as the block list of hostnames and as soon as A becomes up, then that list will be updated as well after 10 minutes.

Here is my background thread code DataScheduler-

```
public class DataScheduler {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void startScheduleTask() {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    callDataService();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // log an error
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    public void callDataService() throws Exception {
        String url = null;

        // execute the url and get the responseMap from it as a string

        parseResponse(responseMap);
    }


    private void parseResponse(Map<FlowsEnum, String> responses) throws Exception {

        // .. some code here to calculate partitionMappings

        // block list of hostnames 
        Map<String, List<String>> coloExceptionList = gson.fromJson(response.split("blocklist=")[1], Map.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : coloExceptionList.entrySet()) {
            for (String hosts : entry.getValue()) {
                blockList.add(hosts);
            }
        }

        if (update) {
            ClientData.setAllMappings(partitionMappings);
        }

        // update the block list of hostnames
        if (!DataUtils.isEmpty(responses)) {
            ClientData.replaceBlockedHosts(blockList);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ClientData class which holds all the information for block list of hostnames and partitionMappings details (which is use to get the list of valid hostnames).

```
public class ClientData {

    private static final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> blockedHosts = new AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>(
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>());


    // some code here to set the partitionMappings by using CountDownLatch 
    // so that read is blocked for first time reads

    public static boolean isHostBlocked(String hostName) {
        return blockedHosts.get().contains(hostName);
    }

    public static void blockHost(String hostName) {
        blockedHosts.get().put(hostName, hostName);
    }

    public static void replaceBlockedHosts(List<String> blockList) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> newBlockedHosts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (String hostName : blockList) {
            newBlockedHosts.put(hostName, hostName);
        }
        blockedHosts.set(newBlockedHosts);
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

When all the servers are up (A,B,C,D as an example) above code works fine and I don't see any `TimeoutException` happening at all from the `handle.get` but if let's say one server (A) went down which I was supposed to make a call from the main thread then I start seeing lot of `TimeoutException`, by lot I mean, huge number of client timeouts happening.

And I am not sure why this is happening? In general this won't be happening right since as soon as the server goes down, it will get added to blockList and then no thread will be making a call to that server, instead it will try another server in the list? So it should be smooth process and then as soon as those servers are up, blockList will get updated from the background thread and then you can start making a call.

Is there any problem in my above code which can cause this problem? Any suggestions will be of great help.

In general, what I am trying to do is - make a hostnames list depending on what user id being passed by using the mappings object. And then make a call to the first hostname and get the response back. But if that hostname is down, then add to the block list and make a call to the second hostname in the list.

Here is the Stacktrace which I am seeing -

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:258)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:119)\n\tat com.host.client.DataClient.getDataSync(DataClient.java:20)\n\tat
```

NOTE: For multiple userId's, we can have same server, meaning server A can get resolve to multiple userId's.

Comment: There is no TimeoutException class in the JRE. Do you mean SocketTimeoutException? And where is it thrown from?

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` is an import I have. It is being thrown from `handle.get` as per stacktrace and here is what I can see in the stacktrace - `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:258)`

Answer (score 0):

In DataClient class, at the below line:

```
public class DataClient implements IClient {

----code code---

        Future<DataResponse> handle = getDataAsync(dataKeys);

//BELOW LINE IS PROBLEM

        response = handle.get(dataKeys.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // <--- HERE
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // log error
        response = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_TIMEOUT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log error
        response = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.ERROR_CLIENT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);

----code code-----
```

You have assigned a timeout to handle.get(...), which is timing out before your REST connections can respond. The rest connections themselves may or may not be timing out, but since you are timing out of get method of future before the completion of the execution of the thread, the blocking of hosts has no visible effect, while the code inside the call method of DataTask may be performing as expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: You explained how `future.get` works in general and that thing I am arleady aware of it. What I am asking is why this only happens when there are any blocked hosts? And why this doesn't happened when all the servers are up.

Comment: Oh..missed that part. Can you please share the thread dumps in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about suggestions, so here are some suggestions:
**1.)** Unexpected return value
Method returns unexpectedly **FALSE**

```
if (ClientData.isHostBlocked(hostname)) //this may return always false! please check
```

**2.)** Exception-Handling
    Are you **really sure**, that a **RestClientException** occurs?
    Only when this exception occured, the host will be added to blocked list!
    Your posted code seems to **ignore logging** (it is commented out!)

```
        ...catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            // make DataResponse
            return dataResponse;
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException ex) {
            // make DataResponse
            return dataResponse;
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            // If it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down.
            // Add this server to block host list 
            ClientData.blockHost(hostname);
            // log an error

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // If it comes here, then it means some weird things has happened.
            // log an error
            // make DataResponse
        }
```